# ¿en MySql Que tan necesario es declarar claves foraneas en una tabla que inevitablemente va a tener registros "Huerfanos"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

tengo una base de datos para llevar un registro de un catalogo y las ventas de este, el caso es que el catalogo se cambia constantemente, por lo que muchos registros de la tabla hija se quedaran sin referencia inevitablemente, es necesario declarar las claves foraneas? por que ahora que estoy tratando de modificar la tabla principal no me lo permite por lo mismo , adjunto imagenes de las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estan en restrict por que es el default , usar Cascade o Set Null no es opcion , pues los registros se tienen que quedar ahi como historial

Aqui muestro el mensaje de error en mi programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que lo mas sencillo seria simplemente eliminar las claves foraneas pero no se que tan adecuado sea esto , muchas gracias por sus comentarios de antemano

Comment: Esto va a dar para opiniones.. Pero en mi opinion, no sirven para nada. Yo nunca declare ninguna clave de ningun tipo. Prefiero que el sistema se ocupe de manterner las relaciones y hacer los deletes y updates como corresponde. Otras bases no declaran las claves foraneas de ningun forma y no pasa nada. Esto es una facilidad, pero no necesariamente obligatorio.

Comment: una clave foranea se puede interpretar como una relación entre dos tablas, y si puede ser o tener un valor `null` el problema con esto es que cambias la intención de esta relación, la cual es, una tabla que posee la clave primaria de otra (o dicho de otra forma: clave foránea), es porque es una tabla hijo y sus registros no pueden existir sin un registro de la tabla padre. Para manejar relaciones entre dos tablas en las que pueden o no existir registros lo mejor es crear tablas intermedias, por ejemplo `ESCUELA` <-> `ESTUDIANTE ESCUELA` <-> `ESTUDIANTE`

Comment: @LPZadkiel de hecho es una tabla intermedia, pero crei que a esas tambien se les ponian claves foraneas

Comment: Lo que llama la atención es que deban existir registros huérfanos... ¿por qué? ¿qué representaría o haría un registro huérfano en tu modelo de datos? ¿por qué no se borra... acaso se relaciona con más tablas y tienes un lío de relaciones? ¿qué hay de la integridad referencial? ¿no será que estás optando por un diseño de datos que no se corresponde con la realidad / necesidades / requerimientos de tu aplicación?